# Texture paint is not showing up on my mesh object but it's showing up on the image texture to the right of my screen

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-painting

I'm trying to texture paint in some details on the object I have created. I have added in the texture image initially in the shading mode > connected the node to the object colour which has worked (I have saved the image) and moved to the texture paint where the image texture shows up (saved the texture image again). when I try to paint onto my object mesh it does not show up in the location that I want it to. (it also at some points does not show up at all anywhere on the object) but my draw marking shows up on the image that is shown on the left of my screen. How can I fix this problem to be able to paint directly on the mesh object and have it show up in the exact place I want it to go? I have tried the following:

- UV > Smart UV Project
- flipping the mesh ( Alt >N > Flip ) (which did allow the paint to show up on the mesh at some points but not where I wanted it to go)
- UV > Unwrap
- Saving the texture image
- Applied scale/rotation/all transformations (incase I missed this prior) --> no changes to the issue.

** One thing I think could be an issue is that my original texture image has been stretched on my object (after several searches and attempts to fix this I've given up on trying to get it to stretch proportionately on my mesh: In shading mode I added the Texture Coordinate but this didn't necessarily do too much ( I tried UV projecting also Unwrapping etc and nothing worked) although I quite like how it appears stretched on my object this could potentially be the issue as to why the paint isn't working.) if any one knows how I could also fix this that would be great as I would love to compare which texture image I prefer (stretched or unstretched)!

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i'm very new to blender so any step by step explanation would be very helpful.

https://snipboard.io/ID1LXQ.jpg

Here is the link to my screenshot^^ please let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Please share your Material settings or the .blend file with the image packed inside the file.

Comment: Thanks for your message, my .blend file is too large to upload so I have left a screenshot of the material settings here: snipboard.io/qGk470.jpg